# Every time I boot into Ubuntu, it shuts down immediately and restarts itself, in a loop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, shutdown

I am trying to boot into Ubuntu system 20.04 LTS. However, every time I turn on, for about 5 seconds loading something, then it suddenly shuts down. 
It then automatically restarts, loading and shutting down .. continue in a loop.  However, if I go into Grub, I can log into the recover mode and get access the root command line interface.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this strange thing?

The following are the only things that are set up in my computer build right now:

- Motherboard: Z590 MSI PRO Wi-Fi
- CPU: i9-10850k and a CPU fan
- RAM: a pair of 16 GB
- M.2 SSD: Samsung 980 Pro NVMe
- Power supply: EVGA 700 GD, 80+ GOLD 700W

UPDATE:

Currently, What I have tried which can log into the OS and even the user interface is to edit the Ubuntu option in GRUB. However, only before 5 minutes the computer shuts down itself.

Specifically, I added `$vt_handoff nomodeset`. When loading, I found that it keeps saying that `Bluetooth hc10: reading intel version information failed (-22)`

Comment: Inspect recently modified log files `ls -lc /var/log`. Copy them to USB stick and examine elsewhere. How's your power supply?

Comment: Can you try to check systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled There could be a service causing the shutdown e.g. malware

Comment: @waltinator my power supply is EVGA 700 GD, 80+ GOLD 700W

Comment: @waltinator Currently, I cannot even go to recovery mode and the root command line interface. Grub interface is the only interface that does not shut me down. any change to see the modified log files?

Comment: Nope. All I can suggest is hardware flakiness. Can you reboot into `memtest86+` and run tests for a few hours? Reseat everything? Clean contacts? Check for obstructions in sockets?  Search the error message online?

Comment: "in my computer build" means we must suspect the hardware - the CPU can't work if it's too hot. More details on "shuts itself down" would help. How do you detect a "shutdown"? E.g. Instant Freeze? Forced logoff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

It seems that there are extra steps that finally make my new computer boot successfully. Here is how I solved this issue completely (I hope).

1. buy a new power supply. I bet the original one is defective which may explain it shuts down immediately after post/grub every time.
2. In the Grub mode, I modified the argument by adding `nomodeset` at the end of the lien of `linux` argument.

One may search for `nomodeset` via google to see related information. As a matter of fact, the safe graphic mode for installation includes `nomodeset`.

See reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04

3. After I successfully installed (using safe graphic mode) and use `nomodeset` argument when boot in, Wifi and Bluetooth cannot use. And I donot want to use `nomodeset` every time.  Fortunately I have Ethernet cable. I follow this link https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=346412 and install `linux-oem-20.04b` via `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b` in the terminal.

From install to complete:

1. in Grub mode use safe graphic mode to install.
2. When boot into the installed Ubuntu, add `nomodeset`.
3. Open terminal and enter `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b`.